# Drools 7 with CDI using Weld

Tags: cdi, drools, weld

I've managed to run Drools with CDI using version 6.3.0.Final, CDI version 1.2 and Weld version 2.30.Final. Using code sample below.

https://github.com/Salaboy/drools-workshop/tree/master/my-first-drools-project

```
 public class App {

    @Inject
    @KSession
    private KieSession kSession;

    public void bootstrapDrools() {
        // The KieSession was injected so we can use it now
        kSession.insert("Hi There!");
        int rulesFired = kSession.fireAllRules();
        System.out.println(">>> Rules Fired: "+rulesFired);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Boostrap the CDI container, in this case WELD
        Weld w = new Weld();

        WeldContainer wc = w.initialize();
        App app = wc.select(App.class).get();
        app.bootstrapDrools();

        w.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same using drools 7.2.0 final.

But I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answer in my blog post
you need to add the following dependency in drools 7 to get those examples working: 
 
            org.drools
            drools-cdi
            ${kie.version}

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: yey! great that you manage to get it working.. it will be really nice if you can send a PR to my repository so other people can benefit from that change :)